# Spring JPA Hibernate many to many insertion duplicate entry for primary key

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

```
    2020-02-29 13:01:14.008 DEBUG 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into users_roles (role_id, user_id) values (?, ?)
2020-02-29 13:01:14.009 TRACE 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2020-02-29 13:01:14.009 TRACE 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [5]
2020-02-29 13:01:14.010 DEBUG 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into users_roles (user_id, role_id) values (?, ?)
2020-02-29 13:01:14.010 TRACE 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [5]
2020-02-29 13:01:14.010 TRACE 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [2]
2020-02-29 13:01:14.025  WARN 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
2020-02-29 13:01:14.025 ERROR 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry '5-2' for key 'PRIMARY'
2020-02-29 13:01:14.027  INFO 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2020-02-29 13:01:14.072  WARN 5200 --- [nio-8083-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
```

Authorities list inside USER entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
@JsonIgnore
private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<>();
```

users List inside Authorities entity

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

I understand that when I save a USER entity, the AUTHORITY entity inside also gets saved, which again saves USER entity and that's what causes the trouble. How can I get around this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your entity classes for User and Authority

Comment: @ShababbKarim I have added necessary fields from entity classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are probably facing is that since you have `@JoinTable` declaration on both entities so you have two insertions with the same composite primary keys in the `Join Table`. You can just remove the annotation from `Authority` class to this:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="authorities")
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

Keep everything else the same. Hopefully this will work.